# Showing existence of a point such that $f'(x) = f(x)$ according to given condition

Tags: calculus

Let $f:[a, b] \rightarrow R$ be continuous in [a,b], differentiable in $(a, b)$ and $f(a)=0=f(b)$. Then
(A) there exists at least one point $c \in(a, b)$ for which $f^{\prime}(c)=f(c)$

(B) $f^{\prime}(x)=f(x)$ does not hold at any point of $(a, b)$

(C) at every point of $(a, b), \mathrm{f}^{\prime}(x)>\mathrm{f}(x)$

(D) at every point of $(a, b), f^{\prime}(x)<f(x)$.

> Approach : Considering $F(x) = f'(x)-f(x)$ we can observe $F(a) = f'(a) , F(b) =f'(b)$ . Also from Rolles theorem we have a point (z) in $f'(x)$ graph in $(a,b)$ such that $f'(z) = 0$ , so we can draw few conclusions like if we consider f'(x) to be >0 for all (a,b) thats not possible because it needs to attain a value 0 too , so . So it can be three cases possible $f'(x)>=0$ , $<=0$  for all $(a,b)$ z is point of local minima of $f(x)$ in this case,  $f'(x) >0$ for $(a,z)$ and $<=0 for [z,b)$ , or $f'(x) <0 for (a,z) ,f'(x)>=0 for [z,b)$ ,
> but from these all cases i am not able to conclude any behavior for F(x) so
> as to get
> f'(x) = f(x) for atleast one point because the last two cases gives the one root of $F(x)$ (in a,b)  but the first case doesnt give it ?

Comment: consider f(x)=0 which of the points are true?

Comment: Yeah from that B,C,D are false . But we cannot say definitely that A is true or not unless a proof @trula thats what i was trying to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the function $g(x) = f(x)e^{-x}$. Then $g(a) = g(b) = 0$, so by Rolle's theorem there is a point $c \in (a,b)$ satisfying $g'(c) = 0$. But
$g'(x) = f'(x) e^{-x} - f(x) e^{-x}$ so that $(f'(c) - f(c))e^{-c} = 0$.

Comment: You have a typo.

Comment: What was the motivation for considering that g(x) to be taken like that ? By what i was trying its not possible to conclude for first case right ? When the graph of f'(x) is >0 for all (a,b) except at z where f'(z) = 0 , in other cases it gives surity right by intermediate value theorem ?

Comment: @Ian thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @ProblemDestroyer the problem is to show that $f'(x) = f(x)$ somewhere, and one approach is to compare it with a function $g$ satisfying $g(x) = g'(x)$ everywhere. That function is $g(x) = e^x$, so I started with the fraction $f/g$ to see what the derivative had to say. It is a common technique.

Comment: I understood thanks, can you once check my method of cases and tell whether i am correct in my post given just above this ? My method just fails to give surity in case of first case only right ?

Comment: With B.C,D wrong you are right, and Umberto just proved that A is right.