# Showing existence of c such that F(c) = 0

Tags: calculus

Let $\mathrm{f}$ be derivable in $[0,1]$, then show that  there exists $c \in(0,1)$ such that $\int_{0}^{c} f(x) d x=(1-c) f(c)$ .

> I considered the function F(z) to be $\int_{0}^{z} f(x) d x -(1-z) f(z)$  we can observe $F(0) = -f(0)$ and F(1) = $\int_{0}^{1} f(x) d x$ , now the only thing which i dont get it , how do we show that $F(0) . F(1) \leq 0$ ? So that by intermediate value theorem we are sure that there is some c such that F (c) = 0 ? Alternate methods are also welcomed like in this post where $e^{-x}$ was used [Showing existence of a point such that $f'(x) = f(x)$ according to given condition](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4442135/1021792)

Comment: You can't show that $F(0)\cdot F(1)\le 0$ because that's not always true. Take for example $f(x)=x-1/3$. Then $F(0)=-f(0)=1/3$. $F(1)=\int_0^1f(x)dx=1/2-1/3=1/6$ So $F(0)\cdot F(1)=\frac1{18}>0$.

Comment: Okay so options were these i think none of the options are correct then , what you think ? @Andrei (A) there exists $\mathrm{c} \in(0,1)$ such that $\int_{0}^{c}\mathrm{f}(x) \mathrm{d} x=(1-\mathrm{c}) \mathrm{f}(\mathrm{c})$
(B) there does not exist any point $\mathrm{d} \in(0,1)$ for which $\int_{0}^{d} \mathrm{f}(x) \mathrm{d} x=(1-\mathrm{d}) \mathrm{f}(\mathrm{d})$
(C) $\int_{0}^{c} \mathrm{f}(x) \mathrm{d} x$ does not exist, for any $\mathrm{c} \in(0,1)$
(D) $\int_{0}^{c}\mathrm{f}(x) \mathrm{d} x$ is independent of $\mathrm{c}, \mathrm{c} \in(0,1)$

Comment: I think it's option (A). You are probably on the right path, it's just that you need to find a point $z$ for which $F(z)$ has an opposite sign than $-f(0)$, and that $z$ is not necessarily $1$.

Comment: Oh i see , there its not written "always exists " just exists written so it can happen in some cases , thanks i got it now @Andrei